# Cloning a disk to a larger disk without overwriting

Tags: external-hdd, data, clone

If I clone a hdd to another (larger) hdd that already has data on it, will the older data get deleted or will new data get added on top of old data?

I need to move data from 2 smaller hard drives to 1 larger drive. After I clone the first drive to the larger drive, I would like to clone the 2nd drive to the same larger drive that has data from the 1st drive.

Will data from the 2nd drive (going to the larger hdd) overwrite pre-existing data on the larger destination drive that came from the first clone, or will it just add data on top of pre-existing data on the larger hdd?

Comment: The question doesn't make sense at all. From that I'm guessing you probably didn't mean "clone" when you said "clone", if you meant "copy"+"past" then yes you are right. If you really meant "clone" the whole drive, then no.

Comment: I meant clone. There is enough room to add data to the hdd that already has data, but it seems that cloning doesn't work that way. If I clone a 2TB hdd to a 2TB hdd, for example, then and I have 1 TB of data on the destination hdd, and am only adding 0.5TB of data to it, the end result will be the destination hdd with 0.5TB of data. Thanks.

Comment: Clone means the target becomes a clone of the source. That's the definition of clone. What can probably be done is that, you can create multiple partitions on target hdd. Then you clone partitions, not disks.

Comment: @DavidDai Thanks. I tried to create an additional partition using 'parted', but it stated that I would be deleting the original partition and its contents if I did.

Comment: You should do more research before asking this question here. You clearly don't have a good enough understanding of disks/partitions/cloning. like, of course repartition the disk would erase data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloning a disk to a larger disk results in whatever was on the smaller source disk, and nothing more. So everything, including prior encryption on the destination disk, will get overwritten with whatever was on the source disk. If the destination disk was 2TB and the source disk was 1TB, the destination disk will now have a partition that is only 1TB.